# Project without garbage collector osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, data-structures, automatic-ref-counting

in my school we recieved task to do project in any programming language, but with custom data structure and programming language can not have garbage collector. It was recommended to use C ++. But I have better skills in objective-c. So I disable ARC in my Xcode project and now I should create custom data structure like ArrayList in Java. I cant use NSMutableArray or NSArray. It is possible working with memory like in C++ and create custom data structure?

Thank you for response

Comment: ARC is not a garbage collector. In Objective-C, you can use `struct`, and also create "custom data structure", which I think are just custom "NSObject", with whatever properties you want?

Comment: @Larme I know that ARC is not a garbage collector, but if I disable ARC I can delete objects manually. What is better for creating custom structure `struct` or new `NSObject`? I want same properties like ArrayList in Java

Comment: @Larme - reference counting **is** a garbage collection technique. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), [this book](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page421.html), and even [this Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2009/01/27/back-to-basics-reference-counting-garbage-collection/) (that's just the first three Google hits I got in order). ARC is a reference counting garbage collector which superseded the previous mark-sweep (not 100% sure on that) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic choices:

1. Use `struct`'s for your data structures and `malloc`/`free` (and friends) for your dynamic memory allocation - just as you might in C(++); or
2. You can use `NSObject` derived classes and `alloc`/`init`/`new`/`retain`/`release` (and friends) for your dynamic memory management. To do this you must disable ARC.

Given this is a school task you might wish to check the second is acceptable - you are still using the Objective-C reference-counting machinery, even though you are calling the operations manually. Your professor may not deem that acceptable.

The first choice is more basic, you will be completely responsible for all decisions on when memory is no longer required. Indeed you may choose to implement your own reference counting or even mark-sweep.

HTH